# Can netbeans be used with noip to be able to log in remotely?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, noip

I would like to know if it is possible to use no-ip to be able to remotely enter a netbeans project raised at the address http://localhost:8084 executed with the "run project" button or if it is possible to do that by modifying something inside of the netbeans. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, connect to your "localhost" server started from inside Netbeans, from another computer?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that

Comment: Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the IP of your machine on your local network.

To do that, follow either of the following tutorials :

[Find your local IP with Windows cmd](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/find-your-local-ip-address-windows-7-cmd/)

[Find your local IP with Mac System Preferences](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=6526)

Afterwards, you can enter that IP instead of "localhost" and that address should work on any computer on the same network, assuming your firewall is not blocking it (by default it should not).

Comment: That works when you enter from the same network, can be accessed remotely, entering from another network configuring with noip?

Comment: I've never used noip, but generally when requesting from another server, you most likely only have to add the port at the end of the address of the machine, and open that port externally (by default it should not already be opened). For example http://yourprivatedomain.com:8084